# What is joint filtration?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, filtrations

Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ with two filtrations $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq0}$ and $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t\geq0}$. The book *Credit Risk: Modeling, Valuation, and Hedging* by Tomasz R. Bielecki and Marek Rutkowski uses the notation $\mathcal{F}_t\vee\mathcal{G}_t$ for the *joint filtration* of $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\mathcal{G}_t$ without giving a definition. So I wonder what is the joint filtration? Is it defined as follows, i.e. the $\sigma$-field generated by the union of $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\mathcal{G}_t$?
$$
\mathcal{F}_t\vee\mathcal{G}_t=\sigma(\mathcal{F_t}\cup\mathcal{G}_t)
$$

Comment: I'd suggest you say which book is it. For all practical needs most likely it's a smallest filtration w.r.t. any of $\mathcal F$- or $\mathcal G$-adapted process is adapted. Guess, your idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you! I added the name of the book

Comment: I suspect that is the joint filtration. Is it not defined anywhere in the book?

Comment: No. It is only in the list of "Basic Notation". I guess because it is not a rigorous math book..

Comment: @L.FrancisCong . The joint filtration is exactly what you think. The symbol $\vee$ is very common in this context.